# Is there an equivalent way to write DATEDIFF(Week,1,[Date]) in a Snowflake query?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm new to Snowflake and attempting to translate existing SQL based queries to a Snowflake syntax. Finding some things don't easily translate. One of them being the week parameter of the SQL DATEADD function.

How does one write DATEDIFF(Week,1,[Date]) in form of a Snowflake query? Is it possible?

---

This question was incorrectly asked. It should have been DATEDIFF NOT DATEADD with respect to the WEEK parameter

I apologize for the misinformation. Should I change (edit) the title or delete and re-post the question properly?

This is what I'm addressing.

SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, **DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,GETDATE())**,-3) Executes in SQL

The same query produces this error in Snowflake
**SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 21 Invalid argument types for function 'DATE_DIFFTIMESTAMPINWEEKS': (NUMBER(1,0), TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9))**

Similarly and a more simplified example I suppose would be:

SELECT DATEDIFF(WEEK,1,GETDATE())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This T-SQL code is doing a truncate to week grain, and then 3 days prior.

```
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,GETDATE()),-3)
```

T-SQL

```
SELECT d, 
    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,d),-3)
FROM (VALUES
('2022-05-19'), 
('2022-05-14'), 
('2022-05-22')
) as t(d)
```

gives:

| d | trunc |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-19 | 2022-05-13 00:00:00.000 |
| 2022-05-14 | 2022-05-06 00:00:00.000 |
| 2022-05-22 | 2022-05-20 00:00:00.000 |

So what you want to actually [DATE_TRUNC](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html)

Snowflake:

```
SELECT d, 
    dateadd(day, -3, date_trunc(week, d))
FROM VALUES
('2022-05-19'::date), 
('2022-05-14'::date), 
('2022-05-22'::date) t(d)
;
```

but for my instance that is giving:

| D | DATEADD(DAY, -3, DATE_TRUNC(WEEK, D)) |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-19 | 2022-05-13 |
| 2022-05-14 | 2022-05-06 |
| 2022-05-22 | 2022-05-13 |

Using WEEK_START session parameter we can set 7 (sunday) and it will be the same as, my current instance of SQL Server 2019..

```
ALTER SESSION SET WEEK_START = 7;

SELECT d, 
    date_trunc(week, d) as a,
    dateadd(day, -3, a) as b
FROM VALUES
('2022-05-19'::date), 
('2022-05-14'::date), 
('2022-05-22'::date) t(d)
;
```

| D | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-19 | 2022-05-15 | 2022-05-12 |
| 2022-05-14 | 2022-05-08 | 2022-05-05 |
| 2022-05-22 | 2022-05-22 | 2022-05-19 |

The sharped eyed will notice those dates don't match, I am super puzzled, in SQL server it appears 22nd May is getting "truncated" to the 23rd.. which is beyond me...

T_SQL:

```
SELECT d, 

    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,d),0),
    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,d),-3)
FROM (VALUES
('2022-05-19'), 
('2022-05-14'), 
('2022-05-22')
) as t(d)
```

| input | trunc | offset |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-19 | 2022-05-16 00:00:00.000 | 2022-05-13 00:00:00.000 |
| 2022-05-14 | 2022-05-09 00:00:00.000 | 2022-05-06 00:00:00.000 |
| 2022-05-22 | 2022-05-23 00:00:00.000 | 2022-05-20 00:00:00.000 |

Comment: I believe DATE_TRUNC is the closest comparable alternative to what I need to translate. I can work out something from this point given your advice. I agree it is strange that May 22 is being truncated to the 23rd. But if I excerpt that one date into a single SQL statement it appears to correctly show May 20th. SELECT DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,'2022-05-22'),-3). Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

The format is:

```
DATEADD(Week,1,[Date])
```

Where the 1 signifies how many weeks you want to add

Edit:
Based on the edited question, see updated answer below

I wasn't familiar with this syntax

SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,GETDATE()),-3)

But based on my reading and some SQL Fiddle, it seems to output the start of "this week" minus 3 days

The equivalent in Snowflake then would be:

```
DATEADD(DAY,-3,DATE_TRUNC(WEEK,GETDATE()))
```

However, taking your example literally, Snowflake would output minus 3 weeks from the start of "this week"

```
DATEADD(WEEK, -3, DATE_TRUNC(WEEK,GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Just to extend:  idenfitiers are quoted with `"`, whereas SQL Server allows to quote them with `[]`

Comment: I added comments to the original question. This was a miscommunication on my part for relaying the actual issue and question. Sorry for that

Comment: @Mark I've amended my answer above. I'm not familiar with your example so I may still be wrong with my answer

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake supports [INTERVAL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#interval-constants) arithmetic:

> You can use interval constants to add or subtract a period of time to/from a date, time, or timestamp. Interval constants are implemented using the INTERVAL keyword, which has the following syntax:
>
> { + | - } INTERVAL ' [ <date_time_part> ] [ ,  [ <date_time_part> ] ... ]'

```
SELECT "Date" + INTERVAL '1 WEEK'
FROM tab
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below format

```
select dateadd(WEEK, 1, to_date('2000-01-31')) as different_day; 
select dateadd(WEEK, 1, '2000-01-31'::date) as different_day;
```

Refer to the below documentation link on the usage

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html#examples